# how do i auto-submit the form when the timer comes to 00:00:00

Tags: javascript, php, forms, date, timer

I have used a countdown timer in my online examination website,the timer is shown via javaScript but problem is that after the 00:00:00 the timer shows negative time.I just want to stop the timer at 00:00:00 and submit a form when the time is over.below is the code that accurately displaying me the timer.

```
<?php
// Upon starting the section
session_start();    
$_SESSION['TIMER'] = time() + 600; // Give the user Ten minutes
?>  
    <script type="text/javascript">
var TimeLimit = new Date('<?php echo date('r', $_SESSION['TIMER']) ?>');

</script>


    <script type="text/javascript">
function countdownto() {
  var date = Math.round((TimeLimit-new Date())/1000);
  var hours = Math.floor(date/3600);
  date = date - (hours*3600);
  var mins = Math.floor(date/60);
  date = date - (mins*60);
  var secs = date;
  if (hours<10) hours = '0'+hours;
  if (mins<10) mins = '0'+mins;
  if (secs<10) secs = '0'+secs;
  document.body.innerHTML = hours+':'+mins+':'+secs;
  setTimeout("countdownto()",1000);

  if((hours==00)&&(mins==00)&&(secs==00))
      document.alert("time is over");
  }

countdownto();

</script>
```

Comment: replace `document.alert("time is over");` with something like `form.submit()`

Comment: Thanks but it is not working even it is not giving alert "time is over". @cmorrissey

Comment: That's because `document.alert` doesn't exist.

Comment: So sorry , just a little mistake from my side.Thanks @SLaks That's because i am a newbie in jS.

Comment: You should look at the errors in your browser's dev tools.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume that your form has an ID attribute with this value `yourForm`.

```
// HTML
<form id="yourForm">[...]</form>

// JS
if((hours==00)&&(mins==00)&&(secs==00)) {
  document.getElementById('yourForm').submit();
} else {
  setTimeout(countdownto, 1000);
}
```

***Note:** Remove your `setTimeout(countdownto, 1000);` before the `if` statement*

#### Alternative way.

You could *kill* the timeout with `clearTimeout()`

```
var myTimeout = setTimeout(countdownto, 1000);

if((hours==00)&&(mins==00)&&(secs==00)) {
  clearTimeout(myTimeout);
  document.getElementById('yourForm').submit();
}
```

[clearTimeout documentation](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_cleartimeout.asp)

Comment: `setTimeout("countdownto()", 1000)` should be `setTimeout(countdownto, 1000)`, i.e. just pass a reference to the function. When a string is passed, it's effectively `setTimeout(new Function("countdownto()"), 1000)`, i.e. the string becomes the body of a new function. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Let's create a index.php file please check it. form submit on timer you can pass time through in javascript CountDown(5,div); function.

```
        <html>
        <body>
          <form action="" method="post" name="mcQuestion" id="mcQuestion">
            Name:<input type="test" name="name" value="Test">
          <div><span id="display" style="color:#FF0000;font-size:15px"></span></div>
        <div><span id="submitted" style="color:#FF0000;font-size:15px"></span></div>
        </form>
        <script>
        var div = document.getElementById('display');
        var submitted = document.getElementById('submitted');

          function CountDown(duration, display) {

                    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;

                  var interVal=  setInterval(function () {
                        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
                        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

                        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
                        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;
                display.innerHTML ="<b>" + minutes + "m : " + seconds + "s" + "</b>";
                        if (timer > 0) {
                           --timer;
                        }else{
                   clearInterval(interVal)
                            SubmitFunction();
                         }

                   },1000);

            }

          function SubmitFunction(){

            submitted.innerHTML="Time is up!";
            document.getElementById('mcQuestion').submit();

           }
           CountDown(5,div);
        </script>

        </body>
        </html>
```